# Images in MvcContrib Grid

Tags: mvccontrib

Topic question:

If i already have helper which returns me image according with parameter (true or false)
I called it like this

and it is returns me `<img src=... />`

I was thinking to use MvcContrib but i cant use `<%= %>` syntax in [embedded blocks](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/22/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-2-new-syntax/comment-page-1/#comment-3596)

Then i find out that it is possible to do like this:

```
p => "img tag src=/images/Available.png/>").Named.(“A”).DoNotEncode();
```

But i want to put conditions, somth that like that:

```
if(item.Availible)
     column.For(p => "img tag src=/images/Available.gif").Named   (“A”).DoNotEncode();
else
     column.For(p => "img tag=/images/Notavailable.gif").Named(“A”).DoNotEncode();
```

i was tried to make it like this:

```
column.For(p => ((item.Availible==false) ? "img tag src=/images/Notavailable.png" : "img tag=/images/Availible.png").Named(“A”).DoNotEncode();
```

but it is doesn't working properly.

is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
column.For(p => p.Available(true) ? "<img src=\"/images/Available.gif\">" : "<img src=\"/images/Notavailable.gif\">").Named("A").DoNotEncode();
```